# Rails 4 Active Admin Problems

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activeadmin

I am having two big problems with Active Admin

When I go to edit a user the encrypted password does not show so essentially i'm having to hack my own site and copy and paste another encrypted password in to the field to update the user - this is the same with create user.

[image: Problem]

The second issue is I cannot create a new user. When I go to create a user nothing happens. I don't get an error. The page just refreshes and the user does not save.

User.rb

```
ActiveAdmin.register User do

controller do
    def permitted_params
      params.permit! 
    end
  end

end
```

I tried destroying my install of active admin and then I reinstalled it and generated the models again but same result. I'm using Rails 4.2.1 and Ruby 2.0.0.

```
gem 'activeadmin', github: 'activeadmin'
```

In development.rb

```
Rails.application.configure do
  # Settings specified here will take precedence over those in config/application.rb.

  # In the development environment your application's code is reloaded on
  # every request. This slows down response time but is perfect for development
  # since you don't have to restart the web server when you make code changes.
  config.cache_classes = false

  # Do not eager load code on boot.
  config.eager_load = false

  # Show full error reports and disable caching.
  config.consider_all_requests_local = true
  config.action_controller.perform_caching = false

  # Don't care if the mailer can't send.
  config.action_mailer.raise_delivery_errors = false

  # Print deprecation notices to the Rails logger.
  config.active_support.deprecation = :log

  # Raise an error on page load if there are pending migrations.
  config.active_record.migration_error = :page_load

  # Debug mode disables concatenation and preprocessing of assets.
  # This option may cause significant delays in view rendering with a large
  # number of complex assets.
  config.assets.debug = true

  # Asset digests allow you to set far-future HTTP expiration dates on all assets,
  # yet still be able to expire them through the digest params.
  config.assets.digest = true

  # Adds additional error checking when serving assets at runtime.
  # Checks for improperly declared sprockets dependencies.
  # Raises helpful error messages.
  config.assets.raise_runtime_errors = true

  # Raises error for missing translations
  # config.action_view.raise_on_missing_translations = true
end
```

I tried changing config.cache_classes = false to true but that does not work either.

I'm not sure what to do here. Any suggestions? I take it this is a bug. Hope it can be fixed. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

It appears you're permitted_params method in your `app/admin/user.rb` file is unconventional and could be causing you problems. You need to add them like this and also put in :encrypted_password if you want to be able to change/edit it ...

```
ActiveAdmin.register User do
  permit_params :email, :password, :password_confirmation, :encrypted_password
  ...
end
```

Comment: This is not working. I don't think that is the proper syntax. WRT the encrypted password it's not editing it that is the problem - it is that it does not show up in the field when editing a user which means I have to copy and paste the password of another user to be able to update the user. Thanks.

Comment: ActiveAdmin.register User do
  permit_params :email, :full_name, :encrypted_password, :admin end Do I need to define create or new here or something?